# How to upload Only Excel file using RegularExpressionValidator?

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2008

i need to control Only ExcelFile uploading with RegularExpressionValidator How can i do that? i need to write a regex pattern in ValidationExpression...

```
 <h3>FileUpload Test</h3>
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="UploadBtn" Text="Upload File" OnClick="UploadBtn_Click" runat="server" Width="105px" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server"
ErrorMessage="Upload Excel only."
ValidationExpression="([a-z]\w*)(.xlsx|.xlsm|.xls)$"
ControlToValidate="FileUpload1">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </div>
```

Comment: Um. What exactly are the filename rules you need? Just for the filename to end in `.xlsx`, `.xlsm` and `.xls`? Or is there anything else?

Comment: periods `.` are meta characters, you gotta escape them as `\.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why you'd validate the file name part - what's wrong about `123.abcd.xls`? Just use

```
^.*\.xls[xm]?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Above given solutions might not work for extensions in upper cases. Enhancing "Penguen"'s solution:

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z0_9].*\bxyz)|([a-zA-Z0_9].*\bXYZ)\b");
```

Replace "xyz" with xlsx and "XYZ" with "XLSX". 
Please give me alternate of this expression, if it is a bulky one.

Answer (score 1):

```
var reg = /^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.xls|.xlsx|.XLS|.XLSX)$/;

if (reg.test($("[id$=FileUpload1]").val()))
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0_9].*\bxlsx\b"   is solution...

Comment: It doesn't even allow a period in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ext = this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
         var cext = ext.toLowerCase();
    switch (cext) {
        case 'xlsx':
```

n code goes here. this checks if nly .xlsx is uploaded